# How do I access Dragons Dogma one from Dark Arisen?

Tags: dragons-dogma

I just bought the game dark arisen and it says on the cover that it includes the entire game one. how do I access game one?
I tried starting it up and it began in the middle of all this stuff and is quite confusing. im new to the game and yes I know, clearly ignorant... but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The start of the game plays out like a short introduction and tutorial. Character creation and the main portion of the game begin shortly after the starting sequence. It is the same for both the original Dragon's Dogma and Dark Arisen.

Dark Arisen works as an expansion and adds a new area and monsters to the original game. The creators simply chose to re-release it as an entire package instead of DLC. You do not need to start separate new games for the original and Dark Arisen; they use the same save data.

Comment: So to paraphrase: By starting a new game, you ARE accessing the original game. Access to Dark Arisen's new content will occur later in your play-through.

Comment: yea, it would kind of suck to start playing an rpg adventure game and not be able to make your own character. that intro is actually pretty important for the games storyline as well as being the first area of the game where you can get familiarized with the controls. again though, it is the same game, they haven't released anything beyond an expansion for dragons dogma's series so far, they are making Deep Down though, which is supposed to be either a sequel or a prequel to the events that take place in Dragon's Dogma.

Comment: That's actually fan conjecture. There's no official connection yet between Deep Down and Dragon's Dogma. The opinion is solely based on the similarity between the first trailer and Dragon's Dogma's gameplay. Also, either way, Deep Down may not even see a North American release.

Comment: you are right about the trailer, just went and watched it again, largely an assumption on my part that it would be related to Dogma. still, it looks like it will be fun and if not be directly related to dragon's dogma then will more than likely have a similar combat system as well as mechanics. after watching the trailer again it honestly looks more like a dungeon delver than an rpg adventure game like Dogma was.